# Achieve Verticle Recyclerview with Horizontal Recyclerview as row file

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to achieve something like this
[image: something like this]

I tried to do with horizontal recyclerview as row file of vertical recyclerview but I am not able to achieve horizontal scroll.

It will be great if anyone helps me out

Here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_player"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lin_main"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </LinearLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Here I am trying to add dynamic views in LinearLyout (lin_main)

Comment: Please share your code for the same & also explain how you've implemented it

Comment: Please post whatever u have tried ! We can only help by viewing what went wrong !

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Create Your ITEM_LAYOUT which you are setting it on recycler view like this as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp">

    //YOUR VIEWS HERE

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView  
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity=""
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp">

        //YOUR HORIZONTAL SCROLL VIEWS COMPONENT

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will help. For more details share your UI xml file here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but here only one view will be scroll and I want to scroll all the views at same time